# Loop script through all subdirectories in current directory?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I imagine this takes the form of a for loop?  I have about 100 lines of code that read csv's and add their contents to a dataframe, but I need to loop it through all of the subdirectories in my current working directory

Comment: How are you listing the files to read into R? Look for an argument along the lines of `recursive` and set it to `TRUE` to get files within subfolders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't given many details, but

```
for (subdir in list.dirs(recursive=FALSE)) {
   ## do stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ben's solution is probably close to what the poster asked, but this might be closer to what (s)he wanted:

```
d = NULL
for (csv in dir(pattern = "\\.csv$",full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)){
  d = rbind(d, read.table(csv))
}
```